# Deploying Spring Web MVC application as a website in a domain root

Tags: spring, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat, ubuntu

I have an web application based on Spring MVC. I want this application to be deployed as website in a domain root. For example:

I want to deploy 'myapp' in the domain root so it can be accessed by:

http://myapp.com

I have apache and tomcat server installed in my ubuntu server 14.04. I also have mod proxy configured, so I have both proxy and reverse proxy now. Which means when I can access port 8080 from port 80 (without typing 8080 in the URL). Now if I deploy this application in tomcat, I can access the application by:

http://mydomain/myapp/

I want to get rid of the mydomain part.

Mentioning, I have the domain registered in the name of the application.

So, it is technically,

> mydomain name = my app name

Any sort of help, or enlightenment will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Deploy the application in the Tomcat `webapps` folder as `ROOT.war`.